# Binding ListView to ObservableCollection of Bitmaps

Tags: wpf, binding, observablecollection

I have some problems with binding my `ListView` to `ObservableCollection<Bitmap>`...

It's my `XAML`:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FrameImages}">
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel
            Width="Auto"
            ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
            ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>

<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border Width="100" Height="75" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="7,5,7,5">
            <Image Margin="5,5,5,5" Width="100" Height="75" Source="{Binding}" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<Bitmap> FrameImages { get; set; }
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = this;

    FrameImages = new ObservableCollection<Bitmap>();
    Bitmap img = new Bitmap(@"E:\test\3047817.bmp");
    FrameImages.Add(img);
}
```

When I add the element, it seems to appear in `ListView`, but it's transparent (just an empty frame):/ I tried to save the bitmap back into file and there were no problems (same as the original one). I don't know why it's not working:(

**[edit]**
Btw. my code works if I replace `ObservableCollection<Bitmap>` with `ObservableCollection<BitmapSource>`. But here's the additional conversion which affects on program's performance... That's why I need `Bitmap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use [System.Drawing.Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) that way in a WPF application. The class does not belong to WPF. It encapsulates a GDI+ bitmap, whereas [WPF is based in DirectX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation). Hence you need to use BitmapSource.

You might however simply bind the [ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of your ListView to a collection of image path strings. The necessary conversion from string to ImageSource is performed automatically by WPF.

If you really need to manually create the bitmaps, you should define your collection as `ObservableCollection<ImageSource>` and create collection elements by something like this:

```
var img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"E:\test\3047817.bmp"));
FrameImages.Add(img);
```

---

You might want to take a look into [Imaging Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748873.aspx). And you should make yourself familiar with the [BitmapSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.aspx) class hierarchy in WPF.